# How to find an aggregate count min count of related objects of related objects?

Tags: django, django-models

I have models with relations likes this:

```
Parent(models.Model):
    pass

Child(models.Model):
   parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Grandchild(models.Model):
   child = models.ForeignKey(Child, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am trying to find a way to annotate a queryset of parent with an aggregate of counts of grandchildren.

For example, say 2 parents: `(A, B)`.
`A` has 3 children: `(A.a, A.b, A.c)`.
`A.a` has 1 grandchild,
`A.b` has 2 grandchildren,
`A.c` has 3 grandchildren,
`B` has 2 children: `(B.a, B.b)`.
`B.a` has 2 grandchildren.
`B.b` has 3 grandchildren.

I want to annotate the parent queryset with an aggregate of the grandchild count for each child on each parent. E.g. aggregating with `Min` would be `A:1, B:2` or aggregating with `Avg` would be `A:2, B:2.5`

I believe this may need `.extra` to accomplish, but I am not sure.

It’s fine if the aggregate function is hardcoded I.e. `Parent.objects.all().annotate_min_ngc_per_c()`, but please explain as best you can do I can reproduce with multiple aggregates.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to get Min or Max would be to use a SubQuery like this:

```
counts = Child.objects.filter(parent=OuterRef('pk'))
counts = counts.annotate(num_grandchildren=Count('grandchild_set'))
counts = counts.order_by('-num_grandchildren').values('num_grandchildren')[:1]
qs = Parent.objects.annotate(min_num_grandchildren=Subquery(counts))
```

It's not aggregate, but it will get you Min/Max.